# 200 Denarri sufficient for purchasing Bread?

Tags: gospels, textual-discrepancies

In Mark 6:37, some disciples comments and indicate that the 200 denarii would have been enough to purchase bread needed to feed the 5000.

> But he answered them, “You give them something to eat.” They said to him, “Are we to go and buy two hundred denarii[a] worth of bread, and give it to them to eat?” (NRSV)
>
> <sup>[a]Mark 6:37 The denarius was the usual day’s wage for a laborer</sup>

But in John 6:7, Philip says that 200 Denarii would not be enough to feed them.

> Philip answered him, “Six months’ wages[a] would not buy enough bread for each of them to get a little.” (NRSV)
>
> <sup>[a]John 6:7 Gk *Two hundred denarii*; the denarius was the usual day’s wage for a laborer</sup>

Is there a contradiction here?

Comment: If a denarius is one day's wages, wouldn't six months' wages be ~156 denarii? No one worked on the Sabbath.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that there is a contradiction. Using the NIV translation:

> They said to him, “That would take more than half a year’s wages [200 denarii]! Are we to go and spend that much on bread and give it to them to eat?” — [Mark 6:37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206%3A37&version=NIV)
>
> Philip answered him, “It would take more than half a year’s wages [200 denarii] to buy enough bread for each one to have a bite!” —[John 6:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A7&version=NIV)

The two verses are not mutually exclusive. Notably, the first doesn't specify how much each person would receive (just saying that the crowd would be given bread).

So putting these two verses together, buying half a year's wages worth of bread would:

- Be shockingly expensive (Mark 6:37)
- Only be enough for each person to have one bite (John 6:7)

There does not seem to be any contradiction between these two statements.